# Getting column with nearest matching number

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a table of numbers, that are ascending, but are not increasing in a pattern, let's call this table t1. In another table, t2 I've got another number, that may or may not be the same to a number in t1. What I want is the number from t1, that is the first smaller number to the one from t2. For example, if there are numbers 6000, 7000 and 8000 in t1, and the number in t2 is 7999 it would get the column with the number 7000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

1. join the number from `t2` to table `t1`
2. compare each row to the number
3. sort by the comparison, select the first row

Implementation:

```
select t1.*
from t1
inner join t2 on t1.column < t2.number
order by t2.number - t1.column asc
limit 1
```

---

Note:  I don't know how many rows are in `t2` so I've given `on t1.column < t2.number` as the join condition -- this may need to be modified to suit your exact needs.

Comment: I don't think ABS is correct in this case, since he wants the "first smaller number"

Answer (score -1):

I hope I understood this correctly. If you want to get largest number from a table which is still less or equal to some other number (7999 in this example) you can do this:

```
SELECT number FROM numbers WHERE number <= 7999 ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I've already done that and it works, but it's not exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 do mysql ghetto row number

Step 2 join the table to itself on it's next highest row_number

Step 3 find the numbers between the number and its next highest number in t2

Step 4 enjoy another wonderful Monday.

```
with temp as (
SELECT  number
        @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM    t1 l
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
order by number
)

with temp2 as (
select o.number,
      case when n.number is null
          100000000
      else
         n.number
      end higherNum
from temp o
left join temp n on o.row_number = n.row_number+1
)

select *
from temp2 o
inner join t2 n on n.number between o.number and o.higherNum
```